# Binary Tree Vertical Order Traversal, what is wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-tree, traversal, tree-traversal

Given a binary tree, return the vertical order traversal of its nodes' values. (ie, from top to bottom, column by column).

If two nodes are in the same row and column, the order should be from left to right.

[image]

[image]

My solution is correct for recording list of nodes in each vertical level, however, it seems the order of nodes at the same vertical level needs to be returned in top to bottom order. According to this specific test case below, 2 is a descendent of 8, so it should appear after 8, but why is my code returns in the opposite order?

[image]

** Please note, because for the simplicity the input example is shown as an array, however, it's actually a tree node object. Please see comments in my code below. 
My code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val) {
 *     this.val = val;
 *     this.left = this.right = null;
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {TreeNode} root
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
var verticalOrder = function(root) {
    var store =  {};
    traverse(root, 0, store);
    var columnKey = Object.keys(store).sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < columnKey.length; i++){
        results.push(store[columnKey[i]]);
    }
    return results
};

var traverse = (node, count, columns) => {
    if(!node) return;
    if(columns[count]) columns[count].push(node.val);
    else columns[count] = [node.val];
    if(node.left) traverse( node.left, count-1 ,columns)
    if(node.right) traverse(node.right, count+1,  columns)

}
```

Comment: I've never seen a weirder tree traversal. Do they give any use case for that?

Comment: No idea, this is just an algorithm practice problem I came across. It would be interesting to know what the use cases are.